# How to make/unmake an element draggable via a child handle in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have created a message box that is draggable at initial run.
The following code is supposed to make a draggable parent div none draggable, when the user hovers on a certain child div to copy a text, that is accomplished successfully via jQuery. the code is also supposed to make the none draggable parent node, draggable again. but for some reasons is fails. I tried Safari console debug and followed the javascript code as at ran step by step. When I hover over the div with class name "messageBoxDescriptionBar" the parent div with class name "messageBox" becomes none draggable, and the draggableOff functions is triggered. But when I hover over the parent node although the draggableOn function is triggered, and the condition is true, and the code inside is executed and the function tries to make the element draggable again, but the result is that the massage box is not draggable again like it was at initial run. why? what am I doing wrong? am I selecting the node incorrectly? I tried selecting it by class name, but result didn't change.

```
function draggableOff(selector) {
var fv__isDraggable = new Boolean;
fv__isDraggable = $(selector).hasClass('ui-draggable');
if(fv__isDraggable) {
    $(function() {
        $(selector).draggable('destroy');
    });
}
}
function draggableOn(selector) {
var fv__isDraggable = new Boolean;
fv__isDraggable = $(selector).hasClass('ui-draggable');
if(!fv__isDraggable) {
    $(function() {
        $(selector).draggable();
    });
}
}
<div style="margin-left: 768px; margin-top: 249px;" onmouseover="draggableOn(this.Node);" class="messageBox messageBoxShaddow ui-draggable">
<div class="messageBoxTitleBar noSelectionNoCursor">Error! Invalid coordinates.</div>
<div class="messageBoxMessageBar noSelectionNoCursor" style="color: red;">
<p> x should be a number.</p>
<p> valid x range is between 0-4.</p>
<p>  y should be within map limits.</p>
<p> maximum y allowed is 4.</p></div>
<div onclick="removeNode(this.parentNode);" class="messageBoxButton noSelectionNoCursor">OK</div>
<div onclick="displayNode(this.parentNode.lastChild);" class="messageBoxButton noSelectionNoCursor">Details...</div>
<div onmouseover="draggableOff(this.parentNode);" class="messageBoxDescriptionBar">
<p> 2 errors has happened:</p>
<p> x coordinate is not a number.</p>
<p> y coordinate exceeds map limits.</p></div></div>
```

Comment: you should play with clases, if it has X class is dragable if not, is not dragable, by the way, this var fv__isDraggable = new Boolean;
var fv__isDraggable = $(selector).hasClass('ui-draggable'); is wrong, you`re overwriting the variable using VAR twice in there, just use the word VAR for defining the variable, bye.

Comment: Thanks for noting my mistake on overwriting the variables, I think I have overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out my mistake, there is no need to declare two functions to turn drag on and off, when a mouse hover event is triggered. jQuery UI already has that functionality through [Draggable Handles](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle). It is possible to make an item draggable only by defining 'handles' or stop it from being dragged, by defining 'cancels'. So  the correct approach is to use:

```
$(function() {
    $(selector).draggable({ cancel: 'selector supposed to stop drag functionality' });
});

$(function() {
    $('selector').draggable({ handle: 'selector supposed to start drag functionality' });
});
```

So I edited the above code to the following and everything works as it supposed to:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.messageBox').draggable({ cancel: '.messageBoxDescriptionBar' });
    });
</script>
<div style="margin-left: 768px; margin-top: 249px;" class="messageBox messageBoxShaddow ui-draggable">
<div class="messageBoxTitleBar noSelectionNoCursor">Error! Invalid coordinates.</div>
<div class="messageBoxMessageBar noSelectionNoCursor" style="color: red;">
<p> x should be a number.</p>
<p> valid x range is between 0-4.</p>
<p>  y should be within map limits.</p>
<p> maximum y allowed is 4.</p></div>
<div onclick="removeNode(this.parentNode);" class="messageBoxButton noSelectionNoCursor">OK</div>
<div onclick="displayNode(this.parentNode.lastChild);" class="messageBoxButton noSelectionNoCursor">Details...</div>
<div class="messageBoxDescriptionBar">
<p> 2 errors has happened:</p>
<p> x coordinate is not a number.</p>
<p> y coordinate exceeds map limits.</p></div></div>
```